# SOAP request logging Tomcat 7 Axis2

Tags: web-services, tomcat, logging, soap, apache-axis

We are trying to log all http requests made to our Tomcat server, in particular SOAP requests.

Our server setup is as follows:
Tomcat 7.0.11
Axis 2
Gentoo Linux

So far we have used the RequestDumperFilter class however this only shows us the header information.

What we require is the ability to view the request body containing the SOAP request XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could make use of some [request processing components](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to view the request body in Tomcat.

From what I know, the [ExtendedAccessLogValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ExtendedAccessLogValve.html) provides the most information about the request but even this is missing the body.

The most simple solution would be to move the logging away from Tomcat and use a proxy server. You place the proxy between the server and it's clients and do the logging in the proxy.

Proxy receives request, logs it, then forwards to Tomcat which generates response, sends it to the proxy which logs it and then sends it to client. The simplest proxy I used (and did its job pretty well) was the [Apache TCP Monitor](http://wso2.org/blog/saliya/3938).

Additionally you could look at something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see if that helps.